# Editing INI file writes garbage/chinese characters to the output file

Tags: vbscript, ini

I want to edit a line in the INI file and below is the code:

```vb
iniWrite "new.INI","Settings","Destination","\Backups\test1\"
'
'Delete a key:-
' iniWrite "game.INI","scores","Alan",""
'
'Delete a section:-
' iniWrite "game.INI","scores","",""

Sub INIWrite(strFile,strSection,strKey,strValue)
  Dim FSO   'File system object
  Dim objReadFile  'INI file to read line by line
  Dim objWriteFile 'Temp INI file to write line by line
  Dim strLine  'String line read
  Dim blnChanging  'Checking mode on\off
  Dim blnFoundSect 'Found a section flag
  Dim blnFoundKey  'Found a key flag
  Dim blnSkipWrite 'Write to temp file on/off
  Dim intKeySize  'Size of key to search for
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  '---- No section error
  If strSection ="" Then Exit Sub

  '---- Equal sign in key name error
  If Instr(strKey,"=") then Exit Sub
  '---- Carriage return and or line feed in value error
  If Instr(strValue,VBCR) or Instr(strValue,VBLF) then Exit Sub

  '---- User supplied section and Value, but no key error!
  If strSection <>"" and strKey="" and strValue<>"" then Exit Sub

  '---- Does INI exist?
  If Not FSO.FileExists(strFile) Then

    '---- You can't delete a section or key from a none existing INI! 
    If strKey="" or strValue="" Then Exit sub

    '---- No INI so make one and add the section\key....then exit.
    Set objWriteFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strFile,2)   
    objWriteFile.WriteLine "[" & strSection & "]"
    objWriteFile.WriteLine strKey & "=" & strValue
    objWriteFile.close
    Exit Sub
  End if

  '---- Set up read and write INI files
  Set objReadFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(strFile,1)   
  Set objWriteFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strFile & "INITMP",2)  
  blnChanging = True
  blnFoundSect = False
  blnFoundKey = False
  blnSkipWrite = False
  intKeySize = Len(strKey)+1

  '---- Scan through INI line by line
  Do While Not objReadFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strLine= objReadFile.ReadLine

    '---- Checking mode (disabled once a key has changed)
    If blnChanging Then

      '------ Key check (only if found section)
      If blnFoundSect Then

        '---- Found key
        If Left(strLine,intKeySize) = strKey & "=" then 

          '---- Delete key
          If strValue="" then
            strLine="="   '<--- skips next line to write

          '---- Or edit key
          Else
            strLine = strKey & "=" & strValue
          End if 

          blnFoundKey=True
          blnChanging = False     
        End if
        '---- Next section
        If Left(strLine,1)="[" Then

          '---- Didn't find key in previous section, so make it now (if not deleting) 
          if blnFoundKey=False and strValue<>"" Then
            objWriteFile.WriteLine strKey & "=" & strValue 
            blnFoundKey=True
            blnChanging = False
          End if

        End if

        '------ Section check
        Else
          If Left(strLine,1)="[" Then 

          '---- If we where deleting the last section, then re-enable writing.
          blnSkipWrite=False

          '---- Found section
          If strLine = "[" & strSection & "]" Then 

            '---- Delete section
            If strKey="" Then 
              blnSkipWrite=True

            '---- Or flag as found
            Else
              blnFoundSect=True
            End if
          End if
        End if
      End if
    End If
    '---- Write line to temp INI, if possible
    If strLine<>"=" and blnSkipWrite=False then objWriteFile.WriteLine strLine
  Loop

  '---- Didn't find section at all so append section\key.
  If blnFoundSect=False and strKey<>"" and strValue<>"" Then
    objWriteFile.WriteLine "[" & strSection & "]"
    objWriteFile.WriteLine strKey & "=" & strValue

  '---- Didn't find key but was the last section, so append key.
  Else
    if blnFoundKey=False and strValue<>"" Then
      objWriteFile.WriteLine strKey & "=" & strValue 
    End if
  End if
  '---- Close files
  objReadFile.close
  objWriteFile.close
  '---- Delete main INI and replace with copy.
  FSO.DeleteFile strFile,True 
  FSO.MoveFile strFile & "INITMP",strFile 
End Sub
```

Below is the file I want to edit (`new.ini`) for `Section= Settings`, `Key=Destination`, `Value=\Backup\folderr1`.

```
[Settings]
GUID_Pushover=
SMTPCharset=
EmailLogNotMan=N
GUID_EmailLog=
SMTPPasswordPrompt=N
LogLinks=N
GUID_WhenPrograms=
FTPIsSFTP=N
GUID_DestFTP=
SFTPHostKeyTooBig=N
DiffOnTop=N
SecurityTypes=0
CompareSecurity=N
PushOverAppToekn=
PushOverDevice=
PushOverMsg=
PushOverTitle=
PushOverUserID=
PushOver=N
IgnoreCreateDateTime=Y
IgnoreDirModDateTime=Y
CreateTimeComp=0
CreateTimeSince=0
CreateDateTime=1899123100000000000
CreateTimeUnit=3
CreateTime=0
DeltaMinSizeMB=500
DeltaExcMasks=
DeltaIncMasks=*
DeltaNoFilters=Y
DeltaExprType=2
DeltaVersionDest=N
RunAfterEnabled=N
RunBeforeEnabled=N
HistoryGridState=
SBFSOnStartUnat=N
SBFSOnStart=N
SBFSPassword=
SBFSUsername=
SBFSPort=0
SBFSHostname=
SBFSIsName=N
SBFSMulti=N
SBFS=N
MTPOnConnectUnat=N
MTPOnConnect=N
MTPSetLocal=N
MTPName=
MTP=
CloudGlacierDays=1
CloudNotUseDelta=N
CloudDBUpload=N
NetDestNoDefault=N
NetSourceNoDefault=N
VerifyExprType=2
VerifyExcMasks=
VerifyIncMasks=*
VerifyNoFilter=Y
CopyResume=N
WarnDelDestPct=0
WarnDelDest=N
WarnDelSrcPct=0
WarnDelSrc=N
NotReplaceWithEmpty=N
BackupSparse=N
BgWatchWaitIdle=N
BgIdleUnit=0
BgIdleInterval=1
BgIdleRun=N
UseLargeCache=N
SFTPHostKey=
EmailSMTPProtocol=0
SMTPProtocol=0
FTPPortMode=0
CloudProxyPassword=
CloudProxyUsername=
CloudProxyPORT=1
CloudProxyHostname=
CloudProxy=N
FTPForceList=Y
FTPAltParser=N
FTPCustomListCmd=LIST -la
FTPUseCustomList=N
BackupEmailExportFolder=
BackupEmailExport=
BackupEmailFilename=%EMAIL_SUBJECT% [%EMAIL_IDORMD5%].eml
BackupEmailIMAP4Folder=
BackupEmailPasswordPrompt=N
BackupEmailPassword=
BackupEmailUsername=
BackupEmailSSL=N
BackupEmailPort=0
BackupEmailIMAP4=0
BackupEmailHostname=
BackupEmailAuth=N
DestIsBackupEmail=N
CloudKBPS=0
CloudS3Emulate=N
CloudUseSSE=N
CloudUseRRS=Y
CloudItemsPerCall=-1
CloudThreads=5
CloudTimeout=60
CloudAccessPolicy=0
CloudCompleteScan=Y
CloudUseSSL=N
CloudBucket=
CloudPasswordPrompt=N
CloudPassword=
CloudUsername=
CloudURL=
CloudType=0
DestIsCloud=N
TreeColour=536870911
RunProgStopInt=N
RunProgStop=
RunProgStartInt=N
RunProgStart=
BgWatchWait=0
PromptFailure=0
SSIgnoreChanges=N
OnInsertHWSerial=
StopWinSleep=N
LogNoSuccess=N
WarnDelAllPct=100
IgnoreEncrypted=N
DestBurnNoSplit=N
EmailLogZipPassword=
EmailLogZipEncLevel=0
EmailLogNotSim=N
CopySymLink=N
SSBFCCChoice=4
SSDFCCChoice=4
SSSFCCChoice=4
CaseFileChoice=4
SSBDCCChoice=4
SSDDCCChoice=4
SSSDCCChoice=4
CaseDirChoice=4
OnlyVSSDest=N
OnlyVSSSrc=N
DestBurnNoProfile=N
EmailDelIgnore=N
LogHistory=0
IgnoreOffline=N
EmailSMTPTransferEnc=-1
EmailSMTPHeaderEnc=-1
SMTPTransferEnc=1
SMTPHeaderEnc=2
TimeLimitUnit=2
TimeLimitValue=23
TimeLimit=N
UseHashingAlways=N
FTPFilenameTrans=Y
GUID=C2200E8851B5420EA683311C235E1D74
ProfileCD=35 12 98 52 137 25 204 19 98 141 38 198 152 26 6 129 152 77 153
DestBurnCache=N
DestBurnLongJ=Y
DestBurnDelim=N
DestBurnISOLevel=1
DestBurnBootSec=1
DestBurnBootSeg=7C0
DestBurnBootEmu=2
DestBurnBootImg=
DestBurnBoot=N
DestNameChanged=1
DestBurnFormat=0
DestIsISO=0
DestIsBurn=N
PriorityAuto=3
RunBeforeTimeoutAbort=N
CompPasswordPrompt=N
FTPPasswordPrompt=N
FTPUseHost=N
FTPCalcDTOffset=N
LogWarnFileGone=N
EmailMaskAttach=N
SFTPKeyPassword=
SFTPKeyFilename=
FldrTreeDisable=N
FSNoFilters=N
RunBeforeNoLog=N
RunAfterChanges=N
DestIsScript=
SilentDestFail=N
SilentSourceFail=N
Scripts=
LogNoSkipped=N
SSRDDetect=N
SSRSDetect=N
DiffShowSkippedRename=N
FldrTreeShowBoth=Y
EmailCompName=
SMTPCompName=
FTPKeepAlive=N
ShowNotes=N
RunAfterLog=N
CopyDesktopINI=N
VerExcMasks=
VerIncMasks=*
VerNoFilters=Y
VerExprType=2
FullDestination=
FastBackupUseFull=N
LogSMART=N
LogDriveSerials=N
SayPrompt=
SayEndFails=
SayEnd=
SayStart=
EmailSBMailbox=N
EmailSMTPBody=N
FullBackup=Y
EmailGetSSL=-1
EmailGetIMAP4Folder=INBOX
EmailGetPasswordPrompt=N
EmailGetPassword=
EmailGetUsername=
EmailGetAuth=N
EmailGetIMAP4=0
EmailGetPort=0
EmailGetHostname=
EmailSMTPSSL=-1
EmailSMTPUsername=
EmailSMTPAuth=N
EmailSMTPFrom=
EmailSMTPTo=
EmailSMTPPasswordPrompt=N
EmailSMTPPassword=
EmailSMTPSubject=
EmailSMTPBCC=
EmailSMTPCC=
EmailSMTPReceipt=
EmailSMTPReplyTo=
EmailSMTPPort=0
EmailSMTPHostname=
DestIsEmail=N
FastBackupType=0
AttribMask=0
AutoClose=
AutoCollapse=Y
BackupFallback=N
BandwidthKBPS=0
BgInteractive=N
BgInterval=12
BgRun=Y
BgUnit=2
BgWarnOnExit=N
BgWatchAttended=N
BgWatchDest=N
BgWatchSrc=N
ClearArchive=N
ClearReadOnly=N
CompEncLevel=0
CompLevel=5
CompNTFSDest=N
CompNTFSSrc=N
CompPassword=
Compression=0
CopyCreateDate=N
CopyDirAttrs=N
CopyDirSec=N
CopyMethod=0
CreateBaseFolders=Y
DataPortMax=0
DataPortMin=0
DelDest=N
DelEmptyDestDirs=N
DelEmptyDestDirsNotFail=N
DelEmptySrcDirs=N
DelEmptySrcDirsNotFail=N
DelFilesForEmpty=
DelSrc=N
Destination=\Backups\test1\
DestIsFTP=Y
DestLabel=Destination
DestOnlyChoice=3
DestOnlyDelDays=0
DestOnlyDirChoice=7
DestPassword=
DestShortcutRoot=
DestUsername=
DisplayLog=N
DisplayLogError=N
DrivePrompt=N
DST=Y
DynFastBackup=N
EjectDest=N
EjectSource=N
EmailLog=N
EmailLogAttachErrOnly=N
EmailLogCompress=N
EmailLogDiffOnly=N
EmailLogErrOnly=N
EmailLogNoAttach=N
EmailZipFilename=
Expert=Y
ExternalIP=
FastBackup=N
FastBackupDelDest=N
FastBackupEquals=0
FastBackupValue=
FastBackupWhen=Never, manually only
FastDifferential=N
FileExt=
FldrTreeShowDest=Y
FldrTreeShowSrc=Y
Flush=N
ForceBinary=N
ForceClose=N
ForceDateTime=Y
FSExcMasks=
FSExprType=2
FSIncMasks=*\:*\*
FTPAllocate=N
FTPBPS=0
FTPClientCert=[Default]
FTPEncMethod=N
FTPHostname=
FTPMDTMSyntax=0
FTPModeZ=N
FTPMustBeEncrypted=N
FTPNotGMT=N
FTPPassive=N
FTPPassword=36 13 198 75 171 56 76
FTPPort=21
FTPProxy=N
FTPQuote=
FTPReadTimeout=60
FTPRetries=5
FTPRetriesSecs=3
FTPSetLocal=Y
FTPTZ=
FTPUsername=backup
FTPUT8=0
HotKeyUnattended=N
IgnoreHidden=N
IgnoreJP=Y
IgnoreNotArch=N
IgnoreReadOnly=N
IgnoreSize=N
IgnoreSystem=N
IgnoreTime=N
ImplicitSSL=N
KeepNewer=N
LoadDest=N
LoadSource=N
LockPrompt=N
LogIgnoreDest=N
LogIgnoreSrc=N
MaxSize=0
MinSize=0
ModTime=0
ModTimeComp=0
ModTimeSince=0
ModTimeUnit=3
NetDestFirst=N
NetDestNoDiscon=Y
NetSourceFirst=N
NetSourceNoDiscon=Y
NeverDelDirs=Y
NotDelReadOnly=N
NotRepReadOnly=N
NoVSS=N
OnInsert=N
OnInsertDrive=0
OnInsertLabel=
OnInsertSerial=
OnInsertUnattended=N
OnShutdown=N
PauseSecs=0
Priority=3
ProfilePassword=
ProfileType=1
ProxyHostname=
ProxyPassword=
ProxyPort=1
ProxyType=0
ProxyUsername=
ReplaceOnReboot=N
RunAfter=
RunAfterDoPause=N
RunAfterFail=N
RunAfterPause=10
RunAfterSim=N
RunAfterWait=N
RunBefore=
RunBeforeAbort=N
RunBeforeCheckVal=N
RunBeforeDoPause=N
RunBeforePause=10
RunBeforeSim=N
RunBeforeValues=
RunBeforeWait=N
RunHotKey=0
SafeCopy=Y
ShellConfirm=N
ShellDirConfirm=N
ShellShowErr=N
ShellShowProg=Y
ShellUndo=N
ShutdownUnattended=N
SingleFile=N
SkipDiff=N
SmartSync=N
SMTPAuth=N
SMTPBCC=
SMTPBody=N
SMTPCC=
SMTPFrom=
SMTPHostname=
SMTPPassword=
SMTPPort=25
SMTPReceipt=
SMTPReplyTo=
SMTPSSL=0
SMTPSubject=
SMTPTo=
SMTPUsername=
Source=D:\Backup\
SourceOnlyChoice=1
SourceOnlyDirChoice=7
SrcLabel=Source
SrcOnlyDelDays=0
SrcPassword=
SrcShortcutRoot=
SrcUsername=
SSDDChoice=2
SSDDMChoice=4
SSDSChoice=2
SSDSMChoice=4
SSLEncryptDC=N
SSMBChoice=7
SSMBChoiceMove=N
SSMDChoice=2
SSMDChoiceMove=N
SSMSChoice=1
SSMSChoiceMove=N
SSNBChoice=7
SSNBChoiceMove=N
SSNDChoice=1
SSNSChoice=1
SyncChoice=1
SyncChoiceMove=N
TimeDiff=2
UpdShortcuts=N
UseCCC=N
UseHashing=N
Verify=N
Version=21
VersionDest=0
VersionDestMaxAge=14
VersionDestMaxVers=3
VersionSrc=0
VersionSrcMaxAge=14
VersionSrcMaxVers=3
WarnDelAll=Y
ZipFilter=.7z,.ace,.alz,.apk,.arc,.arj,.avi,.b1,.bh,.bwt,.bz2,.cab,.cdx,.cfs,.dar,.dmg,.gho,.gif,.gz,.gzip,.ice,.j,.jar,.jpeg,.jpg,.kgb,.lha,.lzh,.lzma,.mov,.mp1,.mp2,.mp3,.mpeg,.mpg,.pak,.partimg,.pea,.png,.qda,.rar,.sfx,.sitx,.sqx,.swf,.tbz2,.tgz,.tlz,.tib,.tif,.tiff,.wim,.wmv,.wvl,.xar,.z,.zip,.zipx,.zoo,.zpaq,.zz
ZipOpen=N
ZipSFX=N
ZipSpan=N
ZipSplit=0
ZipTemp=
LastRun=14
LastRunDT=2015051112072300440
LastSucRunDt=2015051112072300440
```

This is how it looks like after the run (only first few lines from the outputfile):

```
[Settings]
਍䜀唀䤀䐀开倀甀猀栀漀瘀攀爀㴀ഀഀSMTPCharset=
਍䔀洀愀椀氀䰀漀最一漀琀䴀愀渀㴀一ഀഀGUID_EmailLog=
਍匀䴀吀倀倀愀猀猀眀漀爀搀倀爀漀洀瀀琀㴀一ഀഀLogLinks=N
਍䜀唀䤀䐀开圀栀攀渀倀爀漀最爀愀洀猀㴀ഀഀFTPIsSFTP=N
਍䜀唀䤀䐀开䐀攀猀琀䘀吀倀㴀ഀഀSFTPHostKeyTooBig=N
਍䐀椀昀昀伀渀吀漀瀀㴀一ഀഀSecurityTypes=0
਍䌀漀洀瀀愀爀攀匀攀挀甀爀椀琀礀㴀一ഀഀPushOverAppToekn=
਍倀甀猀栀伀瘀攀爀䐀攀瘀椀挀攀㴀ഀഀPushOverMsg=
਍倀甀猀栀伀瘀攀爀吀椀琀氀攀㴀ഀഀPushOverUserID=
਍倀甀猀栀伀瘀攀爀㴀一ഀഀIgnoreCreateDateTime=Y
਍䤀最渀漀爀攀䐀椀爀䴀漀搀䐀愀琀攀吀椀洀攀㴀夀ഀഀCreateTimeComp=0
਍䌀爀攀愀琀攀吀椀洀攀匀椀渀挀攀㴀　ഀഀCreateDateTime=1899123100000000000
਍䌀爀攀愀琀攀吀椀洀攀唀渀椀琀㴀㌀ഀഀCreateTime=0
਍䐀攀氀琀愀䴀椀渀匀椀稀攀䴀䈀㴀㔀　　ഀഀDeltaExcMasks=
```

Comment: Almost 150 lines of code and more than 450 lines of sample input? Seriously? You may want to reduce that to something a little more digestible.

Comment: BTW, it would probably be a lot simpler to just read the INI file into a [dictionary of dictionaries](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/parseini.shtml). That would make it easier to both change particular values and write the data back to a file.

Comment: Thank you Ansgar, i am going to try that also. Not sure if these are BOM characters or is a encoding issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cautionary tale of [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Next script reproduces your issue and shows a right way (maybe one of many) to correct it.

Start with creating a plain text file, save it in the *ASCII* encoding (or *Ansi* encoding, for pedants), i.e. one character == one byte, named `_ASCII.txt`. Then, the script creates further files as follows (described file *names* truncated for better readability):

- `to_utf16` subroutine makes a copy of that `_ASCII.txt` saving it in the *UTF16-LE* encoding with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark); output file name  `_UTF16.txt`;
- `Wrong` subroutine makes a copy of that `_UTF16.txt` file using **default encoding** of `OpenTextFile` and `CreateTextFile` file system methods (an *ASCII* file is assumed for both methods); output file name `_Wrong.txt`. This subroutine reproduces your issue by using **improper encoding** on both input and output files (code copied & pasted from your script);
- `Good` subroutine makes a copy of that `_UTF16.txt` file using **proper encoding** of file system methods mentioned above (***Unicode*** forced); output file name `_Good.txt`.

The script:

```
option explicit
  Dim FSO, objReadFile, objWriteFile, strLine, strFldr 
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  strFldr = "D:\VB_scripts\SO\files_In\"

  to_utf16 strFldr & "30329877_ASCII.txt", strFldr & "30329877_UTF16.txt"
  Wrong    strFldr & "30329877_UTF16.txt", strFldr & "30329877_Wrong.txt"
  Good     strFldr & "30329877_UTF16.txt", strFldr & "30329877_Good.txt"

Sub Wrong( strFile, strElif)
  Set objReadFile  = FSO.OpenTextFile(strFile,1)
  Set objWriteFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strElif,2)
  aux_copy
End Sub

Sub Good( strFile, strElif)
  Set objReadFile  = FSO.OpenTextFile(strFile,ForReading,False,OpenAsUnicode)   
  Set objWriteFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strElif,True,True)
  aux_copy
End Sub

Sub to_utf16( strFile, strElif) 
  Set objReadFile  = FSO.OpenTextFile(strFile,ForReading,False,OpenAs__ASCII)   
  Set objWriteFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strElif,True,True)
  aux_copy
End Sub

Const ForReading=1, ForWriting=2, ForAppending=8
Const OpenAsDefault = -2  ' Opens the file using the system default
Const OpenAsUnicode = -1  ' Opens the file as Unicode
Const OpenAs__ASCII =  0  ' Opens the file as ASCII

Sub aux_copy
  Do While Not objReadFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strLine= objReadFile.ReadLine
    objWriteFile.WriteLine strLine 
  Loop
  objReadFile.close
  objWriteFile.close
End Sub

Wscript.Echo Wscript.Scriptname & " done"
```

**Output**:

```
==>cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\30329877.vbs
30329877.vbs done

==>type D:\VB_scripts\SO\files_In\30329877_Good.txt
[Settings]
GUID_Pushover=
SMTPCharset=
EmailLogNotMan=N

==>type D:\VB_scripts\SO\files_In\30329877_Wrong.txt
਍䜀唀䤀䐀开倀甀猀栀漀瘀攀爀㴀ഀഀ
਍䔀洀愀椀氀䰀漀最一漀琀䴀愀渀㴀一ഀഀ
਍
==>
```

In fact, my text editor reads the `30329877_Wrong.txt` file as follows:

```
[Settings]
਍䜀唀䤀䐀开倀甀猀栀漀瘀攀爀㴀ഀഀ
SMTPCharset=
਍䔀洀愀椀氀䰀漀最一漀琀䴀愀渀㴀一ഀഀ
਍
```

Finally, for illustration: `dir D:\VB_scripts\SO\files_In\30329877*` (truncated) output.

```
22.05.2015  11:21                60 30329877_ASCII.txt
22.05.2015  14:07               122 30329877_UTF16.txt
22.05.2015  14:07               122 30329877_Good.txt
22.05.2015  14:07               128 30329877_Wrong.txt
               4 File(s)            432 bytes
==>
```